If the Law of Large Numbers is True ...
One of my classmates asked the following question in our lecture today (I am paraphrasing):
"The Law of Large Numbers says that if you have a population, a sample and an estimator ... as you feed more and more of your sample to the estimator (i.e. expectation), the value of the sample estimator becomes closer to the population estimator. This is similar to definition of Consistency in mathematics. If the Law of Large Numbers is true, shouldn't this mean that all mean estimators are Consistent"?
My answer to this is something along the following:

Suppose you are trying to look for your friend in a crowd and you know that your friend is wearing a red hat.
If you see someone wearing a red hat - it doesn't mean that this is your friend, its simply someone wearing a red hat. This person is not your person of "interest"
Using the same logic, all estimators will converge to their own true values under larger samples - but it might not converge to the true value of "interest" you are estimating

Is my logic correct?

I do not understand your answer. But from a mathematical statistics point of view, sample mean is consistent for the mean of population exactly because of law of large numbers.

If you take your first observation as your estimator no matter how many more observations you see, then it need not converge to the the population mean unless it is equal to the population mean, though it is an unbiased estimator.  If you take your latest observation as your estimator (also unbiased) then it does not converge at all.

If you read the Wikipedia entries for the law of large numbers and consistent estimator, it might help clear up some of the confusion; but in any case, I think we can also make some clarifications here.
First, one should note that the sample mean is one particular estimator, and it estimates the population mean, which is a parameter.  (One should not use the phrase "population estimator."  We have "population parameters" or "parameters.")
For instance, a normally distributed random variable can be parametrized by the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  The sample mean $\bar X$ of a set of iid observations $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$, defined by $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$ is one estimator for $\mu$.  But it is not the only such estimator; for instance, $X_1$ is an estimator for $\mu$.  It's even unbiased.  It's not a very good one--it relies only on the first observation and does not change with increasing sample size, but it still estimates $\mu$ without bias because its expected value is $\mu$.
Another estimator for $\mu$ is the sample median, $X_{(n/2)}$ (where we use $(n/2)$ to denote either the middle observation or the arithmetic mean of the two nearest to the middle observations).  For a normal distribution, this too is unbiased for $\mu$.  The point here is that the law of large numbers is a statement about the sample mean, which is only one specific estimator of one specific parameter of a distribution, whereas the consistency of an estimator is a statement about an entire class of estimators that do not even have to estimate the population mean, but could estimate any other parameter(s).
Moreover, the law of large numbers is not always true, because certain regularity conditions must apply--in particular, the sample must be drawn from a distribution for which the population mean exists.  As the Wikipedia entry notes, when the sample is drawn from a Cauchy distribution, the LLN doesn't work, because the expectation of a Cauchy random variable does not exist.  And when the sample is drawn from a Pareto distribution with shape $\alpha < 1$, the LLN again doesn't work, because the expectation is infinite.  It is only when the sample is drawn from a distribution that is "well-behaved" that the sample mean enjoys the LLN property.
Regarding estimator consistency, the Wikipedia article describes cases where an estimator is inconsistent, even when the LLN is true.  Because again, the LLN is about the sample mean $\bar X$, not other possible estimators of the population mean.
